# How to get values from textbox comments in pdf document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf document, inside are comments lists of 2 types :
1. Rectangle
2. Text Box

[image]

I want to get values from Text Boxes with c# and itextsharp.

Comment: A sample PDF file would have been better than the screen shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text boxes and rectangles you're referring to are called Annotations. Annotations are defined as dictionaries and they are listed per page.

In other words: you need to create a `PdfReader` instance and get the `ANNOTS` from each page:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("your.pdf");
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    PdfArray array = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (array == null) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Size; j++) {
        PdfDictionary annot = array.GetAsDict(j);
        PdfString text = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
        ...
    }
}
```

In the above code sample, I have a `PdfDictionary` named `annot`, from which I can extract the Contents. You may be interested in some other entries too (for instance the name of the annotation, if any). Please inspect all the keys that are available in the `annot` object in case the `Contents` entry isn't what you're looking for.

Replace the dots with whatever you want to do with the text. `PdfString` has different method that will reveal its contents.

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the original developer of iText (I always assume that people already know this, but I was once downvoted because I didn't add this disclaimer).